# Store objects in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Hello in some function I've got code which save object `{}` to localForage which is nothing but asynchronous localStorage

```
if(vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInRGB &&
   vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInHSL &&
   vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInHEX) {
        $localForage.setItem('colors', {
            inHSL: vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInHSL,
            inHEX: vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInHEX,
            inRGB: vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInRGB
        }).then(function() {
            $rootScope.$emit('localForageUpdated');
        });
}
```

This run ones after button click and store object `colors`. It is working good but when I change color and click button again I want it to save new `colors`object instead of replacing it how it's working now.

So I would like to save `colors1` `colors2` `colors3` and so on. It can be array of objects. s.o.s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save it as an array. Then before saving the next one, get the old value, push the new object onto it, and save that.

```
$localForage.getItem('colors').then(function(colors) {
    colors = colors || []; // initialize as empty array on the first run
    colors.push({
        inHSL: vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInHSL,
        inHEX: vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInHEX,
        inRGB: vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInRGB
    });
    $localForage.setItem('colors', colors).then(function() {
        $rootScope.$emit('localForageUpdated');
    });
});
```

Comment: You'd want to have `$localForage.getItem('colors')` somewhere.

Comment: @BrahmaDev The first line.

Comment: Why do I need `getItem` at the first line? On first function run I will not have any data in cache, will this run then?

Comment: You need to get the item so you can append the new object to the array. The first time it will return `null`, and the line `colors = colors || []` will substitute an empty array for that.

Answer (score 2):

Just store colors as an array and push to that array whenever you want to push a new color.  Then push the array back to local storage.

```
if (vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInRGB &&
    vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInHSL &&
    vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInHEX) {

    $localForage
        .getItem("colors")
        .then((colors) => {
            colors = colors || [];
            colors.push({
                inHSL: vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInHSL,
                inHEX: vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInHEX,
                inRGB: vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1].colorInRGB
            });
            return $localForage.setItem("colors", colors);
        })
        .then((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
            return $localForage.getItem("colors")
        })
        .then((colors) => {
            console.log(colors);
        });
}
```

Comment: @Andreas I'm sorry, I was probably working on my answer at the same time.  Do you want me to delete my answer?

Comment: There are enough differences, like returning the promise instead of calling it directly, you wrapped it in the `if`.